# Applying a function on array that returns outputs with different size in a vectorized manner

Tags: matlab, vectorization

How to apply a function that returns non scalar output to arrays using `arrayfun`?

**For example** - How to vectorize the following code?

```
array = magic(5);
A = cell(size(array));
for i=1:5
    for j=1:5
      A{i,j} = 1:array(i,j);
    end
end
```

This naive attempt to vectorize does not work, because the output is not a scalar

```
array = magic(5);
result = arrayfun(@(x)(1:x),array);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 methods to achieve it:

It is possible to set 'UniformOutput' to false. Then, the result is a cell array.

```
   result = arrayfun(@(x)(1:x),array,'UniformOutput',false);
```

But there is a nice trick that I have found today, the function itself can return a cell. This removes the need of typing `'UniformOutput',false` each and every time.

```
    result = arrayfun(@(x){1:x},array)
```

What is **really interesting** here that I don't have to type `@(X)({1:x})` but I can define it only by using curly bracers `@(X){1:x}`

**Edit(1):** As @Jonas correctly points out, there is no wonder that the regular bracers `()` are not needed, as they are optional. For example, `@(x) x+1` is a valid syntax.

**Edit(2):** There is a small difference between using the curly bracers method or the `UniformOutput,false`. When the input array is empty, their behavior is different.

Comment: You never need the parentheses around the function. But it helps a lot with visibility. Also, `arrayfun` doesn't *really* vectorize the code, it just hides the loop (and will allow Matlab to multi-thread, if it's worth the time). Note that the cell "trick" is very useful with `accumarray` which doesn't have the `uniformOutput` option.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer of Andrey I want to note that it seems, that the first approach, using the option UniformOutput, is slightly faster:

```
>> tic; cellfun(@(x) {single(x)}, data); toc;
Elapsed time is 0.031817 seconds.

>> tic; cellfun(@(x) single(x), data,'UniformOutput',0); toc;
Elapsed time is 0.025526 seconds.
```