# combining string and number in matlab

Tags: string, matlab

Say that I had a matrix of temperature values and a vector corresponding to the depth of the  measurements, e.g.

```
depth = [1,4,8,11,15,16,20];
Temp = rand(1800,7);
```

I would like to insert a row of headings into the first row of Temp, where each heading represents the depth of the measurement. I need the heading to state temp and then the depth e.g. temp1, temp4, temp8, temp11... etc.

I was thinking of doing something like defining 'temp' and then adding the corresponding depth of each column, e.g.

```
varstarter = 'temp';
```

And then use something like 'regexp' but I'm not sure on how this would work. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
arrayfun(@(x) ['temp' int2str(x)],depth,'UniformOutput',false)
```

Here, `@(x) ['temp' int2str(x)]` defines an anonymous function that appends an integer input as characters to the given character sequence `temp`. `arrayfun` then applies this function to every element of the second argument, i.e. `depth`. (Since arrayfun is most often used to produce numerical output, e.g. one number per application of the function, the output usually is a matrix with size in at least one dimension equal to the second input. The `'UniformOutput',false` option thus tells it that this is not the case here (the length of the strings depends on the number of digits of each input), the output needs to be a cell array.)

Use `[ans; num2cell(Temp)];` to combine headings and numerical data into one cell array.

Answer (score 3):

Small improvement of style over the good answer of @arne.b:

```
 arrayfun(@(x) {['temp' int2str(x)]},depth);
```

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044712/applying-a-function-on-array-that-returns-outputs-with-different-size-in-a-vecto/9044716#9044716) for more details.