# matlab: converting a vector to a cell array of strings

Tags: matlab, cell

I'm sure there's a way to do this but I don't know what it is.

Suppose I have a vector

```
v = [1.02 2.03 3.04];
```

and I want to convert this to a cell array using a format string for each element:

```
'   %.3f'
```

(3 spaces before the %.3f)

How can I do this? I tried the following approach, but I get an error:

```
>> f1 = @(x) sprintf('   %.3f',x);
>> cellfun(f1, num2cell(v))
??? Error using ==> cellfun
Non-scalar in Uniform output, at index 1, output 1.
Set 'UniformOutput' to false.
```

Comment: Doh! I wish the error messages were a little more clear. Something like `You may wish to use cellfun(..., 'UniformOutput', false)`

Comment: By the way, definitely you are familiar but I learned recently that `sprintf` works in arrays: i.e. you can use `sprintf('   %.3f',v)` to print all elements. Maybe, you are creating the cells for sth like this?

Comment: That was another possibility (convert to a 2-D string, then to cell array) but has the disadvantage that it pads the rows of the string with spaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated in the error, just provide the parameter of `UniformOutput` as `false`

```
cellfun(f1, num2cell(v), 'UniformOutput', false)

ans = 

    '   1.020'    '   2.030'    '   3.040'
```

Comment: Or use the {} syntax - cellfun(@(x){f1(x)}, num2cell(v))

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution:

```
>> v = [1.02 2.03 3.04];
>> strcat({'   '}, num2str(v(:),'%.3f'))
ans = 
    '   1.020'
    '   2.030'
    '   3.040'
```

Obviously you can transpose the result if you want a row vector.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `{}` syntax:

```
 cellfun(@(x){f1(x)}, num2cell(v))
```

Also check out : [Applying a function on array that returns outputs with different size in a vectorized manner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044712/applying-a-function-on-array-that-returns-outputs-with-different-size-in-a-vecto)