# Adding 2x2 matrix with NaNs

Tags: matlab, sum, nan

More of a general MATLAB question than looking for programming advice -- if I have:

```
y = cellfun(@(x)sum(x(:)), Z, 'un', 0);
```

where there are a combinations of `NaN`'s and real numbers in each cell matrix, when I sum all elements of those matrices per cell, will I always get total = `NaN` because there are `NaN`'s in there, or will they be ignored and just sum the real numbers. The reason I ask is because I am getting:

```
y = [NaN] [NaN] [NaN]
    [NaN] [NaN] [NaN]
    [NaN] [NaN] [NaN]
```

an example cell matrix (cell element) would be:

```
x{1,1} = NaN 2   3
         4   5   6
         7   8   9
```

so I would expect the first element of `y` to be:

```
y{1,1} = 44
```

How am I not getting this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ignore the NaNs, just use vector indexing in your anonymous function, by replacing the colon (`:`)
with `~isnan(x)`:

```
@(x)sum(x(~isnan(x)))
```

So you get:

```
y = cellfun(@(x)sum(x(~isnan(x))), Z, 'un', 0);
```

Comment: y = cellfun(@(x)  {sum(x(~isnan(x)))}  , Z); is more readable. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044712/applying-a-function-on-array-that-returns-outputs-with-different-size-in-a-vecto

Comment: It allows returning cell array output when running cellfun. - Check out the link above

Comment: @Andrey Thanks for the info. I think I'll stick to my answer for now, since it changes less of the OP's original syntax.

Answer (score 7):

You should use `nansum` (from the Statistics toolbox) rather than `sum`.

If you don't have the Statistics toolbox, then you can define `nansum` easily by:

```
function x = nansum(array,dim)

if nargin < 2
    if size(array,1) == 1
        dim = 2;
    else
        dim = 1;
    end
end

array(isnan(array)) = 0;

x  = sum(array,dim);
```

Essentially, the issue is that `sum` tried to sum every element of the input vector. If one of those elements is `NaN` then the entire sum is `NaN` (you can think of `NaN` as representing unknown data - obviously if you don't know what one of the pieces of data is, then you can't know what the sum of all pieces of data is either).

The function `nansum` treats all missing data as zero, so the following code gives the result you expect:

```
>> nansum( [NaN 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9] )
ans =
    44
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have statistics toolbox, you should use [`ignoreNan`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15776-ignore-nan#comments) from the file exchange.

```
   ignoreNan(array,@sum,dim)
```

In your case, you should reshape the matrix first:

```
   ignoreNan(x(:),@sum);
```

It is also more generic than `nansum`, in the sense that it can be used for any function - whether custom or built-in.