# How to sum a series of values, ignoring any NaN values?

Tags: matlab, sum, average, nan

I use MATLAB version R2015a.

I get a series answer from solving the optimal problem several times, and I want to get their sum and average them. However, some of them are NaN. How do I write code to ignore those NaN and sum the others which are not NaN?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you heard of `rmmissing` or `isnan`?

Comment: i have tried the for loop to sum them,or use the sum instruction directly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding 2x2 matrix with NaNs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292462/adding-2x2-matrix-with-nans)

Comment: @CrisLuengo, [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11292462/8239061) is definitely related, though I feel this set of answers if more specific and updated now.

Comment: @SecretAgentMan: I voted to close as duplicate because that question has the same answers as his one (`nansum` and `sum`+`isnan`), even though the questions are not identical. This qestion is more generic, the other one is rather specific, with the cell array complicating the question. If the vote ages away, which seems likely, at least there is a link between the questions now, it will help people find answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use inbuilt functions as suggested in the above answer. If you want to know the logic and use a loop..you can follow as shown below:

```
A = [NaN 1 2 NaN 3 4 7 -1 NaN] ; 
count = 0 ;
thesum = 0 ; 
for i = 1:length(A)
    if ~isnan(A(i))
        count = count+1 ;
        thesum = thesum+A(i) ;
    end
end
```

Comment: Aside from this just being the same as `sum(A(~isnan(A)))`, I don't understand what the point of the `count` variable is?

Comment: **For future readers**: note this is probably the most inefficient solution on this page. MATLAB is optimised for vector operations. Loops can be helpful to foster understanding, but it's good practise to heed the advice of others here suggesting sleeker solutions.

Comment: @Wolfie, thanks for keeping me in check.  I guess I meant a way to get the `count` without looping is `count = sum(~isnan(A))`.

Comment: @Wolfie I agree with you...my intention was to show with loop for learning things. :)

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1:** toolbox free solution using `sum` and `isnan` from base MATLAB.

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 NaN];
sum(A(~isnan(A)))               % No toolbox required
```

**Option 2:** `nansum` (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55348917/8239061) from OP) 
Note: `nansum` requires the Statistics toolbox.

```
nansum(A)                       % Requires Statistics toolbox
```

Code tested using MATLAB R2018b.

---

**Update from comments**
Great suggestion from @[Cris Luengo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7328782/cris-luengo) for those with more recent versions. Requires no toolbox.

```
sum(A,'omitnan')                % No toolbox required
```

Another suggestion from @[Ben Voigt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103167/ben-voigt) for some applications. Also requires no toolbox.

```
sum(A(isfinite(A)))             % No toolbox required
```

Comment: In the more recent versions of MATLAB you can also do `sum(A,'omitnan')`.

Comment: Better than `~isnan(A)` might be `isfinite(A)`, depending on how the other special values ought to be handled.

Comment: Great suggestions.  Will update answer to include your notes w/ attribution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `omitnan` argument

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 NaN];
s = sum( A, 'omitnan' )
```

Note, this is literally the same code as used by the `nansum` function from the Statistics toolbox, which was introduced before R2006a, so I would think compatibility is pretty good.

Comment: When was it introduced? I don’t remember for sure, but I think it was after R2015a? (OP specifies this version)

Comment: Just updated my answer based on @CrisLuengo 's comment then saw your answer here.  My mistake.  Should I delete that portion of my answer or just leave it @Wolfie?

Comment: @Cris I don't have access to that documentation, might be able to dig through change notes, or use `doc sum` in your version of choice to see whether it's present. As I say, it's literally the same code as `nansum` (see `edit nansum`), but I don't know if it always was.

Comment: It makes sense that they would rewrite `nansum` to use the new feature. It likely speeds things up. Core functions are more likely to be implemented in a compiled language, and toolbox functions are more likely to be implemented in M-files (though not always the case).